# Android - XML Shape with particular strokes

Tags: android, android-xml

I want to create a XML rectangular shape with following specification:

> stroke/border top = 0 dp
>   stroke/border left =  3 dp
>   stroke/border bottom = 0 dp
>   stroke/border right = 3 dp

What I have so far is:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient android:type="linear"
        android:angle="90"
        android:startColor="#ff5588"
        android:centerColor="#ff8855"
        android:endColor="#ff5588" />

    <stroke android:width="3dp"/> <!-- the problem is here -->
</shape>
```

But as you know the `<stroke>` tag does not provide any related options for my purpose. Can any one please help me out how can I achieve that shape. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a `layer-list` like below:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#THE_BORDER_COLOR"/>
        </shape>

    </item>

    <item android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">

            <gradient
                android:type="linear"
                android:angle="90"
                android:startColor="#ff5588"
                android:centerColor="#ff8855"
                android:endColor="#ff5588"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```